# how to write an variable from js file in html

Tags: javascript, html

i ve some problems with some variables because i don't know how to take them from .js file and write them in html code. This is the code from, let's say, default.js:

```
$(document).ready(function(){

  function data_info_geo() {
        $.ajax({
      url: "http://ip-api.com/json",
      dataType: 'json',
      type: 'GET'
    }).success(function(data) {
      country = data.country;
      ip = data.query;

            $('#game_data').append('<div id="geo_info_country" style="display:none;">' + country + '</div>');
            $('#game_data').append('<div id="geo_info_ip" style="display:none;">' + ip + '</div>');

    });
    }
```

and i m trying to write these variables on a html page but i don't know how to do it. I hope you can help me, i was looking for this answer for a while, i surfed all google and stackoverflow results but i got nothing good.

edit: i m trying to write those 2 variables:

```
 <div id="geo_info_country" style="display:none;">' + country + '</div>
<div id="geo_info_country" style="display:none;">' + ip + '</div>
```

including the correct country and Ip address.

Comment: What happens with this code?  Does it write the div's to your page?  Is the data coming back properly from your ajax call?  Your div's are hidden, if that could be the problem...

Comment: hello Phillip, i was surfing on some websites when i saw this code, i was thinking that it can help me on my website but when i tried to copy it from "view-soruce://hxxp://site.com", you know, it don;t show you what functions used that guy.

Answer (score 0):

style="display:none" will hide that div element. Not sure if you need to have that inline style within .js file

Comment: even style="display:none" is present in my div block, i just need to call them in page and then show them with  'code'<span id="console_geo_info_ip"></span>    /and/    <span id="console_geo_info_country"> 'code'

Comment: Did you check browser console for any error messages? Over chrome you can check  over console for error messages by pressing F12 button...

Comment: In console is nothing wrong, the website where i took those functions works completely perfect. You know when you are arriving on a html page or any kind of webpage it doesn't show you the source code. I m thinking that i should display these variables with document.write or something like that, right?

Comment: Where have you linked data_info_geo() in HTML? If you have linked it within HTML try to put breakpoints within .js files from chrome source tab...PS. - I wouldn't recommend picking code from any place without the consent of the author...

Answer (score 0):

It's hard to say what the problem is, the two lines appending should be working. From a glance I have a few ideas;

1. The ajax call isn't succeeding, this would explain why you don't see your results (aside from the "display:none" mentionned above)
2. "data_info_geo" function is never called.
3. Something else in your js file breaks before reaching that function.

The console being clear of errors should invalidate 1 and 3, leaving 2.